# Show buttons in the center of an image on hover?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to show buttons in the centre of an image on hovering.

I've managed to do most of it, except the buttons get shown at the bottom? How can I make it so the buttons are reachable clickable within the hover scope?

I've put an example together:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.review-button {
  display: none;
}

img:hover+.review-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <img class="rounded shadow" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600">
  <div class="review-button">
    <div class="bg-green-500 p-3 py-2 text-white">Accept</div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 p-3 py-2 text-white">Decline</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here, in your question. Code hosted externally is susceptible to link-rot, and deletion; also, those trying to help shouldn't have to visit external sites to do so, and those trying to learn from this question, and its answers, should be able to see the starting code as well as the answers in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the absolutely, and use group to animate them on hover since you're using tailwind CSS.

```
    <style>
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
</style>

    <div class="group">
  <img class="rounded-full shadow" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" />
  <div class="review-button:">
    <div class="absolute left-40 top-52 bg-green-500 p-3 py-2 text-white opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-200 group-hover:opacity-100">Accept</div>
    <div class="group absolute left-40 top-64 bg-red-500 p-3 py-2 text-white opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-200 group-hover:opacity-100">Decline</div>
  </div>
</div>
```